# How to cut picture dynamically by Javascript

Tags: javascript, http, dojo

[image]

I have a pictures of icons like this and I know this picture can help to save the times for http links. However, I don't know how to use it.

1. I think I need to get the small icon by coordinate. Is there any libraries can do this? JQuery? Dojo?
2. How can I get this picture? I just know I can show a picture using a  or with the CSS, but I think I need to get this picture by another way. Can the Javascript libraries can also do this job?

Comment: Sprites should be used in conjunction with the CSS `background-image` and `background-position` properties.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/ is the first tutorial I found with Google.

Comment: unless you are using the images in a canvas or webgl context you should be using the css properties.

Comment: Didn't my answer help you? It took me some while to write it... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual use is very simple. Lets have `ui_element` class for buttons. Every button will have the `ui_element` class and the `button_***` class.
Have a look:

```
.ui_element {
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/S02fG.png");
    width: 24 px;    /*May be different for specific buttons*/
    height: 24 px; 

}
.button_home {
    background-position: -23px -23px; /*Move the main image to the deserved element*/

}
```

Then, theoretically, following code should display the red "home" icon:

```
<div class="ui_element button_home"></div>
```

You also can do some fancy tricks, likedifferent display on hover:

```
div.button_home {
    background-position: 0px -23px; /*grey icon*/
}
div.button_home:hover {
    background-position: -23px -23px; /*red icon*/
}
```

Note that my code will not display everything properly aligned. Unless a wery precise pattern was used when generating your image, there is no way to generate CSS code automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There is not way to do this "dynamically" meaning it won't be able to figure out the coordinates. To manually achieve what you're looking for in **CSS** you would use

```
background:url('sprites.png') 0 0;
```

The format being the image itself, how far left, and how far down.